# Retrofit 2 With Two Dynamic Paths

Tags: android, retrofit2

I need to implement an API that has dynamic @path and another @path with RETROFIT 2

myBaseURL: `https://api.github.com`

Example API return :

```
{  
...   
"followers_url": "/user/followers",
"following_url": "/user/following{/target}", 
... 
}
```

I was using like this in the app

```
public interface APIService {
  @GET("{path}")
  Call<Users> getFollowers(@Path(value = "path", encoded = true) String path);

  @GET("{path}")
  Call<Users> getFollowing(@Path(value = "path", encoded = true) String path);
}
```

What should a do to implement the `following_url`, since it has the `{/target}`?

```
  @GET("{path}")
  Call<Users> getFollowing(@Path(value = "path", encoded = true) String path, @Path("{/target}") String target);
```

Retrofit do not find the {/target}.

For now I'm just replacing `{/target}` with "" on the URL, but I don't want to leave this in the app since a want to be able to change my routes in the Back-end.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to confirm if user following another then you need a new interface with:

```
    public interface APIService {
      @GET("{path}/following/{target}")
      Call<Users> getFollowers(@Path("path") String path,@Path("{target}") String target) );
    }
```

The problem is the "/" before target and finally is a parameter in really don't exist a target user you have to replace by a real target user that want know is follow the user

Regards

Comment: The problem is that the @Path is Dynamic, I can't use 
`@GET("{path}/following/{target}")`

Comment: Yes I understood that the path is dynamic, but the {/target} is an informative about the request structure is not for replace as you want in retrofit. Thats means that you could use the same interface but the path parsing needed replace the target in execution time. The Interface means that the {@path} is replaced and generated in the build process. You need a parser in execution time not is as you thinking.